# How do_each_thread() kernel macro works?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

In Linux kernel to loop over all threads alive you use `do_each_thread()` and `while_each_thread()` macros which both defined as :

```
#define do_each_thread(g, t) \
    for (g = t = &init_task ; (g = t = next_task(g)) != &init_task ; ) do

#define while_each_thread(g, t) \
    while ((t = next_thread(t)) != g)
```

which i am very curious how this works since the outer for loop will loop over all main threads but in the inner loop we loop over all threads using `next_thread()` and we repeat whole process for every main thread in the system since the inner loop will only end if both `t` and `g` are same thread. I know i must be missing something but i cant see it right now. so why we loop over all threads again and again. So, this means it will `loop_number = tasks_number * thread_number`; visiting same thread multiple times.

Comment: @ChrisDown I'm sorry for the confusion I mean that ```next_task()``` return the ```main()``` thread of a process and ```next_thread( ) ```just pick the next thread even if its not main thread so the total times this loop will loop = number of main threads * number of all threads . hope its better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop loops over processes (thread group leaders), the inner loop loops over the current (in the loop) process’s threads. Each time the inner loop starts, `g` is the current process’s main thread; `next_thread` is used to iterate over all *that thread group*’s threads, until it loops back to the main thread.

Every thread is visited once, and once only.

Comment: I got it now so ```next_thread``` just loop over this ```main``` threads children and not all threads in the system.